# seed - create nor save not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This does work:

```
result.each do |f|
  rt=ResTypes.new #( :type=>f['type'] )
  rt.type=f['type']
  rt.save()
end
```

This doesn't work:

```
result.each do |f|
  ResTypes.create( :type => f['type'] )
end
```

nor does this:

```
result.each do |f|
  rt=ResTypes.new( :type => f['type'] )
  rt.save()
end
```

Why wouldn't the second or third way?

thx

**edit #1**

this does work:

```
t=IO.read('db/seed-data/list-types.json')
lt_results=JSON.parse(t)
lt_results.each do |i|
  l=ListType.create(i)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have to do with that attribute not being able to be mass assigned. Other than that it looks like it should work.

Comment: right, i guess other seeds I create with an array which seems to work like the edit. Should that be working?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what Maletor suggests, the `type` attribute is not mass-assignable by default. This is because it is set to being the `inheritance_column` in Active Record, which is used for single-table-inheritance. The field is normally set automatically by STI.

To make it so you can assign it, set this in your model:

```
class ResTypes < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = nil
end
```